# Repel ifElse statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I consider myself a novice on Javascript language, and i have a problem with my code. I am trying to simulate a simple if else statement, that relates to if your repel runs out, the program will ask you to use another one. However when i try to run it on Chrome, nothing is printed out on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body> 
<script type = "javascript/text"> 

var repelsInBag = 10; 

  if (repelsInBag > 1){
    document.write("Would you like to use another repel?");
  }else{
    document.write("Repel effect has ran out");
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance !

- Stephen

Comment: Change the type attribute to "text/javascript" or omit it altogether.

Comment: Also, place your script tag at the bottom of the `<body>` tag so that scripts run after the markup renders.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your script tag:

```
<script type = "javascript/text">
```

Is incorrect and needs to be flipped around:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
```

Or just remove it altogether, it's not needed.

```
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I feel so silly actually since the script tag is right at the beginning.

Comment: @Stephen.F No problem the `type` attribute is easy to mess up. That's one of the reasons why now a days it can be omitted in modern broswers, that and JS is the default language.

Comment: I was not aware that the type of the script does not need to be specified ... I've been watching a javascript tutorial on youtube and it like 5 years old, so i don't know if big things has changed on the language or not.

At least i'm aware now :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a page that will validate as **HTML5** and remove the *type* attribute entirely.

http://validator.w3.org/

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

> If this (*type*) attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.